# Disparar evento apenas uma vez

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, eventos

Estou fazendo uma interface no Visual Studio 2015, como faço para realizar um evento apenas uma vez?

Por exemplo:

```
private void textBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    textBox5.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    textBox5.SelectAll();
    textBox5.Text = "";        
}
```

Quando o usuário clica na caixa de texto, a cor muda pra preto, e em seguida seleciona tudo e limpa.

Mas quero que isso aconteça somente uma vez, ou seja, se o usuário clicar de novo não faça nenhuma ação.

Comment: Você também pode perguntar a cor. Se for ForeColor == Color.Black não faz nada.

Comment: Daria certo, porém seria uma gambiarra kkkkk O certo mesmo é como o pessoal das respostas mandaram (textBox5.Click -= textBox5_Click;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Desvincule o evento do componente.

Assim, sempre que o form for "construído" o evento será vinculado ao componente e, quando ele for disparado pela primeira vez, será desvinculado.

Talvez não seja a melhor forma de se fazer, mas sem mais detalhes fica difícil pensar numa forma melhor.

```
private void textBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    textBox5.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    textBox5.SelectAll();
    textBox5.Text = "";

    textBox5.Click -= textBox5_Click;
}
```

Comment: É isso ai mesmo, deu certo!! Obrigado

Answer (score 7):

É bem simples. Não posso dar muitos detalhes porque não vi o código todo, mas em essência é só se desincrever no evento. Se este objeto pode se inscrever, pode fazer o oposto:

```
private void textBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    textBox5.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    textBox5.SelectAll();
    textBox5.Text = "";
    textBox5.Click -= textBox5_Click; //provavelmente isto
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/DisableEvent.cs).

Comment: É isso ai mesmo, deu certo!! Obrigado